# Results of gains function cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r

```
sortedSL=sort(iris$Sepal.Length)
gainsV<-NULL
splitV<-NULL
library(gains)
for(i in 1:NROW(sortedSL))
{
  splitVal=sortedSL[i]
  iris$new=0
  if(sum(iris$Sepal.Length>splitVal)>0)
  {
    iris[iris$Sepal.Length>splitVal,]$new=1
  }
  gainsV<-c(gainsV,gains(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$new))
  splitV <-c(splitV, splitVal)
}
finalSplitV<-splitV[which.max(gainsV)]
```

I type in the code above but saw this error message 
Error in which.max(gainsV) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Please advise.  Thanks.

Comment: It probably means that `gainsV` contains a list as an element, and R can't sensibly unwind it all into a single vector of numbers to compare.

Comment: You should provide a more extensive description of this programming effort. At the moment I think its an "XY problem" of the sort: Please help with problem or type-Y when the real problem is of type-X.

Answer (score 0):

This should admittedly be a comment, but the formatting options for comments are too limited to display the results of str() on complex objects. You are getting errors but you are ignoring what I suspect are important warnings;

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

... coming from this line of code:

```
  gainsV<-c(gainsV,gains(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$new))
```

Looking at

```
 str(gainsV)
 #============
List of 2265
 $ depth            : num [1:2] 99 100
 $ obs              : int [1:2] 149 1
 $ cume.obs         : int [1:2] 149 150
 $ mean.resp        : num [1:2] 5.85 4.3
 $ cume.mean.resp   : num [1:2] 5.85 5.84
 $ cume.pct.of.total: num [1:2] 0.995 1
 $ lift             : num [1:2] 100 74
 $ cume.lift        : num [1:2] 100 100
 $ mean.prediction  : num [1:2] 1 0
 $ min.prediction   : num [1:2] 1 0
 $ max.prediction   : num [1:2] 1 0
 $ conf             : chr "none"
 $ optimal          : logi FALSE
 $ num.groups       : int 2
 $ percents         : logi FALSE
 $ depth            : num [1:2] 97 100
 $ obs              : int [1:2] 146 4
 $ cume.obs         : int [1:2] 146 150
 $ mean.resp        : num [1:2] 5.88 4.38
 $ cume.mean.resp   : num [1:2] 5.88 5.84
 $ cume.pct.of.total: num [1:2] 0.98 1
 $ lift             : num [1:2] 101 75
 $ cume.lift        : num [1:2] 101 100
 $ mean.prediction  : num [1:2] 1 0
 $ min.prediction   : num [1:2] 1 0
 $ max.prediction   : num [1:2] 1 0
 $ conf             : chr "none"
 $ optimal          : logi FALSE
 $ num.groups       : int 2
 $ percents         : logi FALSE
 $ depth            : num [1:2] 97 100
 $ obs              : int [1:2] 146 4
 $ cume.obs         : int [1:2] 146 150
 $ mean.resp        : num [1:2] 5.88 4.38
 #### output at your console would continue for much longer
```

I'm suspicious that this is not the structure you had in mind, but since the goals of this effort were not describe I cannot know this to any degree of certainty.